# Realizar préstamo con array

Tags: java, array

En el siguiente ejemplo represento un programa de una biblioteca, tiene 3 funciones, primero se da de alta clientes, despues se da de alta los materiales (Discos o Libros) y por último **se realiza los prestamos de discos o libros a los clientes a partir del dni del cliente y el id del material(discos o libros)**, y este último paso no encuentro la manera de poder hacerlo de la forma mas sencilla posible.

```
package biblioteca;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CentroCultural {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

       Clientes cliente = new Clientes ();

       Clientes arrayClientes [] = new Clientes [5];

       Discos arrayDiscos [] = new Discos [15];

       Libros arrayLibros [] = new Libros [15];

       int contadorClientes = 0;

       int contadorDiscos = 0;

       int contadorLibros = 0;

       int opcion;

       do{

            cliente.imprimirMenu();

            opcion = teclado.nextInt();

            switch(opcion){

                case 1:

                    if (contadorClientes < arrayClientes.length) {

                        String dni,nombre;

                        System.out.print("DNI del cliente : ");
                        dni = teclado.next();

                        System.out.print("Nombre del cliente : ");
                        nombre = teclado.next();

                        teclado.nextLine();

                        cliente = new Clientes(dni,nombre);

                        arrayClientes [contadorClientes] = cliente;
                        contadorClientes++;

                        System.out.print("Cliente registrado correctamente");
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println();


                    }else{

                        System.out.print("Se han alcanzado el máximo de clientes permitidos");
                        System.out.println();
                    }

                break;
                case 2:


                    System.out.println("¿Que quieres insertar?");
                    System.out.println("1. Disco");
                    System.out.println("2. Libro");
                    opcion = teclado.nextInt();

                    while (opcion != 1 && opcion != 2){

                        System.out.println("Numero no valido");
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println("1. Disco");
                        System.out.println("2. Libro");
                        opcion = teclado.nextInt();

                    }

                    switch (opcion) {
                        case 1:

                        if (contadorDiscos < arrayDiscos.length) {

                            int codigo;
                            String titulo,autor,discografica;

                            System.out.println("Escribe el codigo");
                            codigo = teclado.nextInt();

                            System.out.println("Escribe el titulo");
                            titulo = teclado.next();

                            System.out.println("Escribe el autor");
                            autor = teclado.next();

                            System.out.println("Escribe la discografica");
                            discografica = teclado.next();

                            teclado.nextLine();

                            disco = new Discos(codigo,titulo,autor,discografica);

                            arrayDiscos [contadorDiscos] = disco;
                            contadorDiscos++;

                            System.out.print("Disco registrado correctamente");
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.println();}


                            break;
                            case 2:

                            if (contadorLibros < arrayLibros.length) {

                                int codigo,num_paginas;
                                String titulo,autor;

                                System.out.println("Escribe el codigo");
                                codigo = teclado.nextInt();

                                System.out.println("Escribe el titulo");
                                titulo = teclado.next();

                                System.out.println("Escribe el autor");
                                autor = teclado.next();

                                System.out.println("Escribe el numero de paginas");
                                num_paginas = teclado.nextInt();

                                teclado.nextLine();

                                Libros libro = new Libros(codigo,titulo,autor,num_paginas);

                                arrayLibros [contadorLibros] = libro;
                                contadorDiscos++;

                                System.out.print("Libro registrado correctamente");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println();
                        }
                        break;
                        default:
                        }



                break;
                case 3:

                   // Realización de préstamo, a partir del DNI del cliente y el id del material(libro o disco).

                break;    
                default:
                   System.out.println("");

            }
        } while(opcion !=4);  
    }  

    }
```

Clase Clientes.

```
package biblioteca;

    public class Clientes {

        private String dni;
        private String nombre;

        public Clientes(String dni, String nombre) {
            this.dni = dni;
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        public Clientes() {
        }

        public String getDni() {
            return dni;
        }

        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        public void setDni(String dni) {
            this.dni = dni;
        }

        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        public void imprimirMenu() {

            System.out.println("1. Dar de alta a clientes.");
            System.out.println("2. Dar de alta a materiales (ambos tipos).");
            System.out.println("3. Realización de préstamo, a partir del DNI del cliente y el id del libro.");
            System.out.println(""); // Salto de linea.

            System.out.print("Escoge una opcion del 1 al 3 : ");

        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Clientes{" + "dni=" + dni + ", nombre=" + nombre + '}';
        } 
    }
```

Clase Material.

```
public class Material {

    private int codigo;
    private String titulo;
    private String autor;

    public Material(int codigo, String titulo, String autor) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "codigo=" + codigo + ", titulo=" + titulo + ", autor=" + autor + " ";
    } 
}
```

Clase Discos.

```
    public class Discos extends Material {

    private String discografica;

    public Discos(int codigo, String titulo, String autor,String discografica) {
        super(codigo, titulo, autor);
        this.discografica = discografica;
    }

    public String getDiscografica() {
        return discografica;
    }

    public void setDiscografica(String discografica) {
        this.discografica = discografica;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Código : "+ getCodigo() + ", Titulo : "+ getTitulo() + ", Autor : " + getAutor() + ", Discografica : " + discografica;
    } 
}
```

Clase Libros.

```
    public class Libros extends Material{

    private int num_paginas;

    public Libros(int codigo, String titulo, String autor,int num_paginas) {
        super(codigo, titulo, autor);
        this.num_paginas = num_paginas;
    }

    public int getNum_paginas() {
        return num_paginas;
    }

    public void setNum_paginas(int num_paginas) {
        this.num_paginas = num_paginas;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Código : "+ getCodigo() + ", Titulo : "+ getTitulo() + ", Autor : " + getAutor() + ", Número de páginas : " + num_paginas;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con "lo más sencillo posible"? Es conveniente que compartas tu código para realizar préstamos, e indicarnos el problema que tienes.

Comment: Me refiero a que acabo de empezar a programar y si pudiera ser algo lo más sencillo posible para comprender el código. Ese es el código que tengo hecho de momento, me falta realizar los prestamos de un libro o disco a un cliente y asignarselo que no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Entiendo, pero debes realizar el código para realizar el préstamo por tu cuenta, y cuando tengas un problema o un obstáculo que te impida avanzar, con mucho gusto te ayudaremos. Si te proporcionamos código, en esta etapa no te ayudará mucho, porque precisamente lo que debes aprender es la lógica para resolver un problema. Intenta realizar un préstamo en papel, imaginarte como sería el proceso y que datos y estructuras necesitarías, luego traslada eso en código. Ánimos!

Answer (score 4):

**Solución**

Te sugiero agregar un atributo en la clase Cliente de tipo Material y/o en la clase Material un atributo de tipo Cliente. Con esto se logra explotar el paradigma de orientación a objetos; estos atributos vinculan las instancias de las clases cuando exista un préstamo entre ellas.

Dejo una ilustración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El atributo material (de la clase Cliente) sería:

```
private Material material;
```

El atributo cliente (de la clase Material) sería:

```
private Cliente cliente;
```

Nota: se agregan sus correspondientes getters y setters.

**Nuevas problemáticas**

Se debe tener cierto cuidado en la integridad lógica de la realidad; es decir si la realidad no permite que un Material sea prestado a dos Clientes al mismo tiempo, eso se debe chequear al momento de la asignación.

No es necesaria la bi-direccionalidad, incluso puede dar problemas si se asigna de forma incorrecta, ej

```
Cliente c1 = new Cliente();
Cliente c2 = new Cliente();
Material m1 = new Libros();

c1.setMaterial(m1);
m1.setCliente(c2);//aquí se aprecia el error de asignación.
```

Saludos